# Can't add bower component css into assets pipeline in Rails 4.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to add bower component (angular ui-grid) to my angularJS + Rails 4.2 application.
The component is working fine in development env, but in production env it works without its css.

I've installed the component via a bower to *vendor/assets/bower_components*
and made the following changes in order to integrate it into the assets pipeline:

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js
//= require_tree .
```

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

**assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << %r(.*.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff)$)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ui-grid.css )
```

I executed *rake assets:precompile* which generated the following output:

```
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/application-546acf8e965ef660d80be61d1314dcef.js
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/application-bf4c9902bcb508f0250e847dc63c3321.css
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid-70f73890ff81d1e19e758473a9ff1f1e.eot
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid-069439f9e57a19c07fad6095a9056446.svg
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid-f681537c8135d9deb670ceadfb8eddd4.ttf
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid-a3319d6298bca8dd2bcaae48735afe00.woff
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e4c812e8c30abb98e787ab176cb74129.eot
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-c9450138a7b29547267148145ba65c3e.svg
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7ef334f0e220af09b5aa3a8283ccaa6a.ttf
Writing /source/myapp/public/assets/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-97811df08b2f65e376ad5b37fc5f315b.woff
```

For some reason the ../assets/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css is missing from the precompile output!

When I run my Rails app in production env (in development it works fine), the ui-grid component is running (=> the ui-grid javascript was integrated successfully into the assets pipeline), but without its css (all ui-grid.css classes), and it looks horrible.

How do I add the ui-grid.css into the assets pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. In addition to doing a sass import, you also need to do a sprockets import.

add

`*= require angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css`

To the manifest, and you should be fine.

Comment: In which file I should add the sprockets import?
This line is invalid in *application.css.scss*

Comment: in application.css.scss, at the beginning of the file - like you would include any other asset-based css file. What error are you getting?

Comment: When I run *rake assets:precompile* I get the error:  `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "= require angul..."`

Comment: are you putting it like so in the commented out section at the beginning of the file? can you post your application.css.scss file?

Comment: Thanks! Adding this line inside the commented code of the *application.css.scss* added *ui-grid.css* to the assets pipeline (thus I accept the answer).
Now the problem is that the rest of the ui-grid assets (.svg .woff .ttf .eot) are not compiled correctly (although appears in the output of the assets:precompile task) - in the browser console I get 404 errors on them all, i.e., 404 on `http://localhost:3000/assets/ui-grid.woff`

Comment: How do I solve the issue of the 404 on http://localhost:3000/assets/ui-grid.woff?